# How to optimise feature extraction from text runtime for NLP project

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

I'm doing an NLP project in Google Colab (Python) with a text dataset involving ~100,000 instances. Right now, for every instance, I'm doing feature extraction for about 5-10 features and it's taking roughly 5-10 minutes every time I try to run the code. Because I'm trying out different kinds of features, I'm running the feature extraction process quite a number of times and the total run time adds up after a while.

I suspect this could be because my code is not very efficient, currently relying on list comprehension, map together with iterations. The code takes up a lot of memory as well due to the size of the data and how it stores multiple copies of the text.

So I'm wondering whether there is a better way to perform feature extraction to speed up the process (and save space). I heard about numpy having vectorised operations but am not sure how to go about doing that.

This is a skeletal version of my code.

```py
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([["The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
                    "Energy is sustainable if it meets the needs of the present without compromising the ability of future generations to meet their needs."],
                   ["The scientific literature on limiting global warming describes pathways in which the world rapidly phases out coal-fired power plants, produces more electricity from clean sources such as wind and solar, shifts towards using electricity instead of fuels in sectors such as transport and heating buildings, and takes measures to conserve energy.",
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s"]], columns=['text1', 'text2'])


def process(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    # Other techniques like stemming and lemmatization

    return tokens

def get_features(text1, text2):
    features = []

    feature1 = len(text1) + len(text2)
    features.append(feature1)
    feature2 = len([word1 for word1 in text1 if word1 in text2])
    features.append(feature2)

    # Continued for about 5-10 features. Some features involve multiple steps like doing named entity recognition and creating features from there

    return features

df.loc[:, 'text1_tokens'] = df.loc[:, 'text1'].apply(process)
df.loc[:, 'text2_tokens'] = df.loc[:, 'text2'].apply(process)

features = df.apply(lambda x: get_features(x['text1_tokens'], x['text2_tokens']), axis='columns')

df.loc[:, 'feature1'] = list(map(lambda x: x[0], features))
df.loc[:, 'feature2'] = list(map(lambda x: x[1], features))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
feature2 = len([word1 for word1 in text1 if word1 in text2])
```

This line has runtime complexity of `words_in_text1 * words_in_text2`. Depending on the size of those texts, you'd likely get a large speedup by getting just the *set* of words in `text2`.

You are also creating a list that in that same line that is just wasted. If order of words in the text doesn't matter throughout, possibly using a `collections.Counter` or similar object would give further speed increases.

For example:

```py
from collections import Counter


text1_counts = Counter(text1)
text2_counts = Counter(text2)
feature2 = sum(count for word, count in text2_counts.items()
               if word in text2_counts)
```

---

If you have many more features with similar problems, addressing these should speed up your feature extraction.

Comment: Thank you. Can I check whether you mean something like `unique = set(text2)` and `feature2 = len([word1 for word1 in text1 if word1 in unique])`? Or is there a way of simplifying the list comprehension further

Comment: Yes, looking up words in `unique` will be much faster than in `text2`. Look at my edits, adding the `Counter` object so that the iteration over `text1` is also faster (though admittedly only if you are planning to use the counts more than once).